# Rails : sort for the specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I'm designing a table on view. For instance, they have two columns are `ID` and `name`. When a user clicks to the `ID` column, I want the data will be sorted by `ID`. Similarly, if a user clicks `name` column`, the data` will be sorted by `name`.

My question is :

Is there any way to put this into the model (database model), hence, when user click one column, its status will be saved and the database will look at this to return record according to this status.

if not, how I put this code in view.

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this railscasts #228 http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
end
```

When you have functional sort columns, you then will need to save it to the db

A basic table with: user_id, page_name (or table_name), sort_column, sort_direction

Then when the user loads a page you would check against the saved settings and load them if they exist, if they don't you can load a default.

This is the idea, I do not have time to write the code for it, but it should be fairly straight forward.

**Update:**

Since I had to do this at work, I will post my code.

The railscast above implements the following three functions, which allow for sorting on a column.

application_controller.rb/or specific_controller.rb

```
def sort_column
  Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

And the controller that uses it

```
def index
  @products = Product.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end
```

***Now***, in order to remember what the user selected for the sort and to use that instead of always loading the default sortable column we need to create a table for the `user_preferences`

create a migration for the preference table like

```
create_table :user_preferences do |t|
  t.string :action
  t.string :preference

  t.references :user
end
add_index :user_preferences, :user_id
```

When we search now (path -> 'specific_controller#index?direction=asc&sort=name') we need to save/update the user's preference

```
def index
  preference = UserPreference.find_by_user_id_and_action(User.current_user.id, params[:action])
  #Save/update preference based on column sort
  if params[:sort]
    unless preference.nil?
      preference.update_attribute(:preference, "#{params[:sort]},#{params[:direction]}")
    else
      preference = UserPreference.new(:user => User.current_user, :preference => "#{params[:sort]},#{params[:direction]}", :action => params[:action])
    end
  end
  populate_table_based_on_preference(preference)
end

def populate_table_based_on_preference(preference)
  unless preference.nil?
    @products = Product.order(preference.preference.split(',')[0]+ " " + preference.preference.split(',')[1])
  else
    @products = Product.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end
end
```

Then we need to update our methods (sort_column/direction -> What column are we sorting/ Which direction? )

```
def sort_column
  #What are we sorting on?
  preference = UserPreference.find_by_user_id_and_action(User.current_user.id, params[:action])
  unless preference.nil?
    preference.preference.split(',')[0]
  else
    Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name" 
  end
end

def sort_direction
  preference = UserPreference.find_by_user_id_and_action(User.current_user.id, params[:action])
  #what is the search direction
  unless preference.nil?
    preference.preference.split(',')[1]
  else
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc" 
  end
end
```